# php returns invalid json

Tags: php, arrays, json

The following php code returns an invalid json error not sure why

```
<?php
include("dbConnect.php");

$sql = "SELECT QID, Question, Answer,CatID FROM Questions";


$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('qid'=>$row[0],
'question'=>$row[1],
'answer'=>$row[2],
'catid'=>$row[3]
));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

when I run the link to the php it returns this data:

```
{"result":[{"qid":"1","question":"Question 1","answer":"Answer 1","catid":"1"},{"qid":"2","question":"Question 2","answer":"Answer 2","catid":"2"},{"qid":"3","question":"Question 3","answer":"Answer 3","catid":"3"},{"qid":"4","question":"Question 4","answer":"Answer 4","catid":"1"},{"qid":"5","question":"Question 5","answer":"Answer 5","catid":"3"},{"qid":"6","question":"Question 6","answer":"Answer 6","catid":"3"}]}
```

and I tried running the link to the php that returns the json data using this [json formatter website](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

I get these errors:

```
Error:Invalid media type, expecting application/json.[Code 28, Structure 0]

Error:Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.[Code 29, Structure 0]

Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 114]

Error:Invalid characters found.[Code 18, Structure 114]

Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 116]

Error:Invalid characters found.[Code 18, Structure 116]
```

If I try copying the resulting json data I get a valid JSON format but when I try running it from the php link that is stored on my server I get the above errors

**UPDATE:**

[link to php](http://aamaa.comli.com/retrieve.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the JSON string, it's the header data.
You must specify the `Content-Type` header manually, otherwise it will send the output as text/html:

```
<?php
include("dbConnect.php");

$sql = "SELECT QID, Question, Answer,CatID FROM Questions";


$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('qid'=>$row[0],
'question'=>$row[1],
'answer'=>$row[2],
'catid'=>$row[3]
));
}

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: I still get the same errors.. I have updated my question with the link to the php file if you can please check it in the json formatter link and see the resulting errors

Answer (score 1):

Add `header('Content-Type: application/json', true);` to your code before `echo json_encode ()` to set the correct mime type.

The other error messages from the validator website are curious; i cannot see invalid characters or fields that are not wrapped in double quotes. Maybe, the validator website has some bugs.

Comment: I still get the same errors.. I have updated my question with the link to the php file if you can please check it in the json formatter link and see the resulting errors

Comment: Your server appends some analytics content to the output: `<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->`; this invalidates your json output. Can you disable this behavior in your server settings?

Comment: disabling analytics did the job .. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

add header in php file..

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");