# Javascript weird Fetch() issues, fails on a specific JSON data/format

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

```
var url1 = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
var url2 = 'http://teaconcepts.net/temp/api_test.php';


fetch(url1)
.then(function (result){
    console.log("Result received");

    return result.json();
}).then(function(data){
    // console.log("data received",data[1]['name']);
    console.log("data received",data);


}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("Error in Fetch",error.message);
});
```

I'm fetching valid JSON data from both URLs, but with slightly different structure

```
 var url1 = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
var url2 = 'http://teaconcepts.net/temp/api_test.php';
```

If I load data from URL1, things are fine. But if I load url2 i get an error "Failed to fetch"

What gives???

See demo: http://jsbin.com/yaxecewopu/1/edit?js,console

Comment: The second request does not have CORS setup. Chrome will not allow you to fetch from a server cross domain. If you have control over the server, you'll need to setup [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Fetch API cannot load http://teaconcepts.net/temp/api_test.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://null.jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the same-origin policy. If you run this JavaScript on `http://teaconcepts.net` it will work. Or, you can get teaconcepts.net to respond with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to allow any origin or specific origins (such as jsbin.com and stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2):

Here issue with second url is encoding problem, check second url here

Paste your url in 
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and check what is issue with return type of json. or else see below image [result of second url json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLBLD.png)

if you author for that php file see the below thread to solve issue [php returns invalid json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104139/php-returns-invalid-json)

Answer (score 1):

The second URL refers to a site that doesn't allow cross-origin requests. The browser therefore disallows access via `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest`.